# Redirecting and returning data in SvelteKit form actions

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

You can send data after form submission by including it in the form action return. This data is accessed through the `$page.form` store.

If you want to redirect to a different page on form submission, you redirect to a different page by [throwing a `Redirect` object](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#anatomy-of-an-action-redirects). The `redirect` method only has two parameters (`code` and `location`), with no options to return data (unlike `fail` for example).

Is there any way to return data **and** redirect on form submission, besides just adding it all as URL parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: why not just add data to url as query string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. It would not work reliably, as redirecting while also keeping page state cannot be done without JavaScript. The application may also have to perform a reload after it has been updated which would interrupt this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a limitation of SvelteKit. HTTP redirect consists of url and optional status. Reference [Response: redirect() static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirect_static).

> Is there any way to return data and redirect on form submission

If this can happen consecutively, do the [redirect on the client-side](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto). This requires JavaScript, and would therefore not work if the browser JS is not available.

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
  import type { ActionData } from './$types';

  export let form: ActionData;

  // Check the form value and redirect accordingly
  $: if (form?.ok) goto('/redirect/url');
  $: if (form?.url) goto(form.url);
</script>
```

If you are using external DB, etc. that can store the submitted data, in the form action function

1. INSERT into DB
2. Throw a redirect
3. Let the new page's server load function SELECT the data from the DB.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot! Just wanted to say that `redirect` required another parameter, a URL:
`throw redirect(301, '/')`